# How to ensure Button has focus when QML tab is activated, rather than TextField?

Tags: button, focus, qml, textfield

In QML, I have a Tab containing a TextField and a Button. How do I ensure the Button has focus when the tab is selected, instead of the TextField? Setting "focus:" to true and false, respectively, does not do it. In the code below, the goal is for btnRefresh to have focus when a tab is selected, instead of txtName.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2  // For TabViewStyle

ApplicationWindow {
   visible: true
   width: 640
   height: 480
   title: qsTr("Hello World")

   TabView {
      id: tabView
      anchors.fill: parent
      anchors.margins: 20
      tabPosition: Qt.BottomEdge

      Tab {title: "Tab 1"; source: "mytab.qml"}
      Tab {title: "Tab 2"; source: "mytab.qml"}

      style: TabViewStyle {
         frameOverlap: 1
         tab: Rectangle {
            color: styleData.selected ? "steelblue" :"lightsteelblue"
            border.color:  "steelblue"
            implicitWidth: Math.max(text.width + 4, 80)
            implicitHeight: 20
            radius: 2
            Text {
               id: text
               anchors.centerIn: parent
               text: styleData.title
               color: styleData.selected ? "white" : "black"
            }
         }
         frame: Rectangle { color: "steelblue" }
      }
   }
}
```

mytab.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
   anchors.fill: parent

   GridLayout {
      columns: 2
      anchors.fill: parent
      rowSpacing: 10

      RowLayout {
         Layout.columnSpan: 2

         Label {
            id: lblName
            text: "Name:"
         }

         TextField {
            id: txtName;
            text: "a name"
            Layout.preferredWidth: lblName.implicitWidth * 1.5;
            focus: false
         }
      }

      TextArea {
          id: textSetup
          text: "Text Area"
          Layout.columnSpan: 2
          Layout.fillWidth: true
          Layout.fillHeight: true
      }

      Button {
          id: btnRefresh
          Layout.columnSpan: 2
          Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
          text: qsTr("Refresh")
          focus: true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add code that proves it doesn't do it?

Comment: I updated the question to show dependence on Tab, and provided code example.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you switch tabs in a TabView, a signal handler `onVisibleChanged` is called on the two tabs (one that disappeared and the one that appeared) since the visibility of these tabs has changed. You can try adding following code to your Tabs:

```
Tab { 
id: tab1
title: "Tab 1"; source: "mytab.qml" 
onVisibleChanged: { 
        if (visible)  tab1.item.funcSetFocusOnButton();  
    } 
}
```

Please note the way a function is called on a tab using `item`.
Now in "mytab.qml", you create a javascript function `funcSetFocusOnButton` which sets focus on your button. So your mytab.qml will have this additional code:

```
Rectangle {
    //Your GridLayout{}

    funcSetFocusOnButton() {
        btnRefresh.forceActiveFocus();
    }
}
```

Note here that the function `funcSetFocusOnButton` should be a direct child of your base item (rectangle here). Hope this helps!